# How to view a website as it appears on mobile safari from desktop safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browser, mobile-safari, websites

On chrome on desktop, it's easy to view a website as it appears when viewed on chrome on many other devices. That is, simply <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to open dev tools, then clicking on the 'Toggle Device Toolbar' lets you select which device you want to view the site as. For example, this is stackoverflow.com viewed from chrome on **desktop** (it can be made to show what would be seen by a user accessing the site from chrome on an iPhone 8):

[image]

#### Question

How do I view a website as seen from other devices **safari** running on **desktop**?

I've tried [changing the user agent](https://wccftech.com/how-to-view-mobile-websites-in-safari-on-macos-tutorial/), which simply tells the website to serve what it normally would to a mobile device, however, this doesn't affect the fact that it's still being viewed on a desktop browser, which is very different to a mobile one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Develop menu > Enter Responsive Design Mode  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>

You can then choose between a selection of devices…

<sup>Click for larger image</sup>
[image]

If you don't have that menu open already, it's in Safari Prefs > Advanced